# Parsing binary point data with javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js, binary-data, arraybuffer, buffer-geometry

### The Problem

I am receiving binary data from an API that describes a group of colored points in 3D space. The intent is to parse the points and use them in a buffergeometry in Three.js.

I'm in a little over my head here when it comes to working with binary formatted data so I need your help.

---

### About the binary data coming from the API:

The binary data starts with a header in the following format:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 13632 // varies depending on the query
```

The header is followed by a blank line, and then these points in this format:

Every 32 bytes:

- X: double (8 byte)
- Y: double (8 byte)
- Z: double (8 byte)
- R: unsigned char (1 byte)
- G: unsigned char (1 byte)
- B: unsigned char (1 byte)
- 5 garbage bytes to fill out the remaining space

---

### Where I'm at so far:

Assume that **binaryPoints** variable holds the raw binary data from the API. As I understand it so far, I must first add the data to an arrayBuffer with a byte-size of 32 (size of each point). Next, I add that buffer to a DataView object in order to manipulate it.

```
  // create a 32-byte arrayBuffer (each point takes up 32 bytes)
  const buffer = await binaryPoints.arrayBuffer(32);

  // create a dataview of the buffer to read the points
  const data = new DataView(buffer);
```

So I don't have much yet. I think I need to account for the space taken up by the header here by implementing an offset, and I'd like to get the number of points from the header.

```
  // temporary hard-set values
  const numPoints = 1000;
  const offsetFromHeader = 100; // bits
```

From some examples and other SO questions I've seen, I believe I should loop through the buffer 32 bytes at a time, reading out the xyzrgb values as I go. It might looks something like:

```
  // offset is in bits, increases by 256 each iteration (32*8)
  for (var i=0, offset=offsetFromHeader; i<numPoints; i++, offset += 256) {
    // Go through each xyz value, using Float64Array (double) to store that value
    const xFloat64View = data.getFloat64Array(offset);
    const yFloat64View = data.getFloat64Array(offset + 64);
    const zFloat64View = data.getFloat64Array(offset + 128);

    // Go through each rgb value, using Uint8Array (1 byte unsigned int) to store that value
    const rUint8View = data.getUint8Array(offset + 192);
    const gUint8View = data.getUint8Array(offset + 200);
    const bUint8View = data.getUint8Array(offset + 208);

    // just ignore the final bits
  }
```

... but truth be told, I was unable to figure out what to *do* with the information once I got to this point. In some of the examples I've found, the loop runs through binary data with only one type of information (in my case it would be as if I only had the X value).

Should I be creating a new plain javascript array of points and adding the values like this:

```
// psuedo code
var points = [];

// in the loop
points[i].x = data.getFloat64Array(offset);
```

That's probably not the case, because I plan on transcribing the Typed Arrays directly into the Three.js bufferGeometries in the next step, and keeping a [large] extra plain JS array adds overhead.

---

### Next step: Getting the points into Three.js bufferGeometry

I'll be using the points in Three.js' bufferGeometry to render the pointcloud. I understand that this informs the output I want from the previous part.

It might look something like:

```
const bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();


let vertices = new Float32Array(); // xyz
let colors = new Float32Array(); // rgb

bufferGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
bufferGeometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));

const points = new THREE.Points(bufferGeometry, material);
scene.add(points);
```

---

I know that this is all very loose so far, but I'm just flailing around in the dark and writing this all down helps me think it through.

Comment: It looks like you're specifying your offsets in bits instead of bytes.. is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a doubled gUint8View.. second one should be bUint8View..

I think you want the DataView api...
Then you can just do like...

```
var x= view.getFloat64(0); 
var y= view.getFloat64(8); 
var z= view.getFloat64(16);
var r = view.getUInt8(24); 
var g = view.getUInt8(25); 
var v = view.getUInt8(26);
```

Also.. are you sure about a "100 bit" header or do you mean bytes? Seems strange that your data source would start at a weird non-8 bit boundary and that would complicate parsing TREmendously.

The THREE side of your code looks roughly right.

You're on the right track :) I just did a similar app to parse the HYG star catalog and make a point cloud of stars....

Good stuff!

Comment: Thanks, @manthrax! Edited out my typo- a consequence of copy-pasted psuedo code. I _was_ curious about bits vs. bytes for offset; I switched to bytes and it helped. As far as the headerOffset is concerned, that was just a hard-set value. I'm having trouble figuring out how to discern the initial offset. Do I search the buffer for the first instance of the newline character? I'm going to split this question into multiple smaller questions.